I can't connect to mysql database from jupyter on ubuntu
File C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection_cext.py:328, in CMySQLConnection._open_connection(self)
    326         self.converter.str_fallback = self._converter_str_fallback
    327 except MySQLInterfaceError as err:
--> 328     raise get_mysql_exception(
    329         msg=err.msg, errno=err.errno, sqlstate=err.sqlstate
    330     ) from err
    332 self._do_handshake()


ProgrammingError: 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'stedman'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

I was trying to connect to mysql in my ubuntu installation using my user and password credentials but I couldn't connect to mysql from jupyter, it kept displaying "Access denied for this user"
However, I could use the credentials in ubuntu and gain access to mysql and the databases.

Looks like you used the wrong password

When you say this I was trying to connect to mysql in my ubuntu installation using my user and password credentials Do you mean you were using the same creds as you would use to login to Ubuntu? If so the MySQL user/password would normally be different. Did you try using root as the username and leaving the password blank. That is often the default state of a MySQL instance?
